# how can i detect when tile is traversable

Tags: c++, vector, random, 2d

I am trying to detect if "start" and "end" and in a traversable location using a vector of bools called "map" but when I run the program both start and end sometimes appear in a location that is non-traversable. I have included a small section of my code which deals with initializing the locations of start, end uses the same code.

```
start = tydle::Vector(rand() % 512, rand() % 512);
end = tydle::Vector(rand() % 512, rand() % 512);
nodes.resize(0);
int tempx = start.x;
int tempy = start.y;
int Coord = (tempx % 512) * tempy;
while (!map[Coord]){
    start.x = rand() % 512;
    start.y = rand() % 512;
    tempx = start.x;
    tempy = start.y;
    Coord = (tempx % 512) * tempy;
}
```

below is a section of code used elswhere that uses the same while loop and works fine:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++){
        tempNodes[i].resize(2);
        tempNodes[i][0] = rand() % 512;
        tempNodes[i][1] = rand() % 512;
        int mapCood = (tempNodes[i][0] % 512) * tempNodes[i][1];
        while (!map[mapCood]){
            tempNodes[i][0] = rand() % 512;
            tempNodes[i][1] = rand() % 512;
            mapCood = (tempNodes[i][0] % 512) * tempNodes[i][1];
        }
    }
```

Comment: WTH is `tydle::Vector`??

Comment: tydle is a class, sorry, should have mentioned that, tydle::Vector is a 2d coordinate system

Comment: Post a [MCVE] demonstrating your problem please.

Answer (score 0):

I would wager the problem comes from the way that you're calculating array indices:

> `int Coord = (tempx % 512) * tempy;`

If `map` represents a rectangular array of `bool`, of size `width * height`, then you should access your array like

```
array[(y * width) + x]
```

so that an increase of one in your `y` position shifts the index by `width` locations, or one row (since elements are stored contiguously) and an increase of one in your `x` position shifts exactly one index.

Comment: it does but in a odd way it is just a long list from 0 to 512*512 in a single dimention array, i tried that and it did not work, map is the vector of bools

Comment: @simfrek have you done the same array index calculation throughout your project? There might be more to fix

Comment: @simfrek I don't understand what you're trying to do with `(tempx % 512) * tempy`. For example, if you have tempx = 3 and tempy = 2, it'll calculate the same index as tempx = 2 and tempy = 3, thus causing a collision and not giving a unique index for each x and y

Comment: that is why i am only using the remainder of 512 of x, (start.x % 512), sorry the tempx and tempy are used instead of directly accessing start.x and start.y as wanted to make sure that wasnt the issue as had to cast as int before

Comment: @simfrek If you're using % to prevent exceeding bounds and wrap around, then try this: `((tempy % 512) * 512) + (tempx % 512)` Otherwise, your array indices are broken and it may be time to hit the books

Comment: that is a valid option although it does not solve my problem